# Searching for Python strings without regex in PyCharm

Tags: regex, string, pycharm, jetbrains-ide

I often need to search hard-coded strings (e.g. `'foo'` or `"bar"`) in my projects (whether it in single file or throughout the whole project). Because Python allows defining them in two ways - single-quoted and double-quoted I have to write regex `['"]foo['"]` for searching, which is a bit tedious to do every time.

I tried using PyCharm search filter  "In String Literals" but it also includes searching in larger strings (e.g. `'xxx foo xxx'''`), so it is not an option as well.

Therefore, question is if there is a better way to search for strings than provided RegEx?

Comment: Note that `['"]foo['"]` is not entirely correct; in particular it doesn't deal with nested `'` and `"` correctly: for instance, `"hello, 'botanich'"` is one string, but your query will match `"hello, '` as the first string.

Comment: @Stef thank you for correction, I didn't think about it. Though, this is a rare case and shouldn't appear too often in search, so my regex still works well enough for me - otherwise, it gonna grow larger